# htaccess rewrite remove parent directory and php extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a hand rewriting some urls.
What i need is to remove the folder name from the url and also remove the php file extension.
Example:

I need `mysite.com/foldername/about.php`
to become
`mysite.com/about/`

I must say that i have several php static files that need to be access from
`mysite.com/filename/`
instead of
`mysite.com/foldername/filename.php`

Thank you in advance for your time.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[.*]/?$ foldername/$1.php#{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

If you are not using the QUERY_STRING (i.e. you have no $_GET parameters) then you can remove the #{QUERY_STRING}

Note, this will rewrite everything in your root to foldername/NAME.php

If you wish to exclude certain paths (such as css, js files and others), I recommend you do:

```
RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^*.css$
RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^*.js$
RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^*.php$
RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^*DONTREDIRECT*$
RewriteRule ^/[.*]/?$ foldername/$1.php#{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Comment: THanks Gazler, Is there any way to do this per file basis and not as regex?
Because i still have some php files  that need to be accessed as foldername/filename.php

Comment: Sure, you can either exclude them using RewriteCode (which I would recommend) or you can do: RewriteRule ^/about/?$ foldername/about.php#{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]